# CSS/Primefaces: Hide datatable header

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

How to hide datatable header from css

Css :

```
<style>
.ui-datatable.borderless thead th, .ui-datatable.borderless tbody,
    .ui-datatable.borderless tbody tr, .ui-datatable.borderless tbody td {
    border-style: none;
    background: #eee !important;
}
</style>
```

xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable id="idData" value=""
styleClass="borderless" >

<p:column>
    //Component
</p:column>

<p:column>
    //Component
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Show the generated html and use html and css as tags. That is where the issue is, not in jsf (or datatable)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide the entire `thead`, use the following:

```
.ui-datatable.borderless thead {
  display: none;
}
```

Confirmed that it works at my web app.

Comment: if it doesnt work even with this way, try also with `display: none !important`

Comment: thank Apostolos, i had try this style... hide the header and make column width not same like picture.... but my css function for datatable to hide header, border line, and turn background to transparent.. how to combine this style? and not change the width column.

Comment: didnt understand what exactly you want to achieve. make the theader background transparent or hide it?

Answer (score 0):

The below CSS worked fine For primefaces datatable. hide-column-names is the user defined CSS class name.

```
.hide-column-names table thead tr {
    display: none;
    background: transparent !important;
```

}